# VueJS + V-IF : passing props gives container in computed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

So I am trying to create a computed to evaluate two conditions of my prop but when I evalute `row` in `hasWebsite` I get the entire container instead of getting the prop value. I can't figure why.

template

`<a v-if="hasWebsite(props.row)" class="btn btn-success" :href="props.supplier.websiteUrl" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>`

computed

```
computed: {
hasWebsite: function(row){
  console.log(row)
  return !!(row.status !== 100 && row.supplier.websiteUrl);
}
```

Comment: Computed is for properties, this looks it should be a method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation - [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#computed) do not accept arguments, as instead represent a variable with custom `get` and `set` methods. Meaning, computed properties are accessed, not invoked.

In your case [methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods) should be used. It will be reactive and re-computed when argument changes.

```
methods: {
  hasWebsite (row) {
    return !!(row.status !== 100 && row.supplier.websiteUrl);
  }
}
```

Usage inside the template stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a method instead of `computed` property :

```
  methods: {
     hasWebsite: function(row){
      console.log(row)
      return !!(row.status !== 100 && row.supplier.websiteUrl);
   }
```